# C++ OpenCV include error 'file not found'

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a problem using OpenCV 4.1.2 in C++. I have this `CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project( Barcode-cpp )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_library( src
        src/VideoVeed.h
        src/VideoVeed.cpp
)
add_executable( program
            program/main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries( program
                    src
                    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

As you can see I have two folders with source code:

- `program` contains `main.cpp`
- `src` contains `VideoVeed.h` & `VideoVeed.cpp`

When I include OpenCV in `main.cpp` like this: `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, it works fine. But when I include OpenCV *(the same way)* it gives the error `fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found`.

I think I'm doing something wrong in my `CMakelists.txt`, but I can't figure out what exactly.

I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the line, `target_include_directories()`, so that the OpenCV include directories are *included* in your executable:

```
add_executable( program
        program/main.cpp
)
target_include_directories(program PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Depending on the version of OpenCV you are using, you may need 
 to use `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS` instead:

```
add_executable( program
        program/main.cpp
)
target_include_directories(program PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

**EDIT**: OpenCV 4.1.2 populates the variable `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS`, so this is the variable you should use. See [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html) tutorial.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work... Where do I need to put it. Perhaps I placed it at the wrong place?

Comment: It should be placed *after* defining your `program` target, after the call to `add_executable()`.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn;t work for me than... Thanks for trying tho!

Comment: I have OpenCV 4.1.2 btw, maybe that helps.

Comment: @mHvNG Yes, the version helps. I edited my answer, and it may help to clear your CMake cache and run CMake from scratch.